# Live Tile - UWP (Windows 10) - Url in source image not working

Tags: c#, url, win-universal-app, live-tile

I try to put url on source of an image in XML of my LiveTyle Template, but certain urls do not work properly. I tested the App Notifications Visualizer by Microsoft and do not work, however put the link in the browser the image is returned.
Any idea what is the problem?

**Link does not work in the template:**

***Encode*:** http%3A%2F%2Fproxycache.app.iptv.telecom.pt%3A8080%2FMeoHandler%2FImageProxy.ashx%3Fwidth%3D200%26url%3D1%2F5%2F55046d06-98e0-4aa3-be7d-f6996152b8ad_c_anatomia-16x9.jpg

***Decode:*** http://myimages.com/today/hello?width=200&url=9_c_xpto-16x9.jpg

both not working :(

**Extract template:**

```
string localImageURL = "ms-appx:///Assets/MyImage70x70.png"; 

XmlDocument _myXML = new XmlDocument(); 

string PeekSlide=
                      @"<tile>
                       <visual>
                      <binding template=""TileMedium"" branding=""name"">
                       <image src=""{0}""  placement=""peek"" hint-overlay=""20""/>
                      <image  src=""{1}"" placement=""background""/>
                      </binding>
                      </binding>
                      </visual>
                      </tile>";

    var _myTile = string.Format(PeekSlide, localImageURL, myWebUrl);
    _myXML.LoadXml(_myTile);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your ImageURL contains `&`, which has a specail meaning in XML. So XML cannot analysis your image Url. Replace `&` with `&amp`; instead. Details refrence the [Entity References](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) part . After replaced, your image Url should be

```
 <image src="http://myimages.com/today/hello?width=200&amp;url=9_c_xpto-16x9.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sunteen. Work perfectly after change "&" to "&amp;". One question:

In C# I have System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(url), but in my BackgroundTask I not access this. 

I try the: url= url.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&apos;");
but this way is very very boring. Have any way to do this with native methods? like the first I write?

Thanks

Comment: Try WebUtility.UrlEncode (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx)

Comment: @fipcurren88, It seems no API for this.Although it has,the core logic should be replace.   Replace is good way I think. But wrap it in a method and call the method every time you want to use.

Comment: @Sunteen, Hi, thanks for your reply, I try var url= Windows.Foundation.Uri.escapeComponent(url); but without success:

Error above the "Uri": 'Uri' is inaccessible duw to its protection level. Cannot access private class 'Uri' here.

Thanks

Comment: @fipcurren88 Also I found a document you can refence [How to locate and replace special characters in an XML file with Visual C# .NET ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316063). Additional, if my answer can help you, can you please mark it as answer?

Answer (score -1):

The content of the field '_myTile ' will be a XML with the path to an image on the assets, not from the Web.

Why you don't try this:

```
string localImageURL = "http://proxycache.app.iptv.telecom.pt:8080/MeoHandler/ImageProxy.ashx?width=200&url=1/5/55046d06-98e0-4aa3-be7d-f6996152b8ad_c_anatomia-16x9.jpg"; 

XmlDocument _myXML = new XmlDocument(); 

string PeekSlide=
                      @"<tile>
                       <visual>
                      <binding template=""TileMedium"" branding=""name"">
                       <image src=""{0}""  placement=""peek"" hint-overlay=""20""/>
                      <image  src=""{1}"" placement=""background""/>
                      </binding>
                      </binding>
                      </visual>
                      </tile>";

var _myTile = string.Format(PeekSlide, localImageURL);
_myXML.LoadXml(_myTile);
```

HTH,

Thomas